# Why the similarity transformation matrix in jordan block decomposition can not be chosen unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, matrix-decomposition

We know that any matrix can be transformed into its jordan form by similarity transformation. But why can't we choose a Matrix S with its inverse $S^-1$ as unitary matrices for non diagonilizable matrices.

Comment: You can't even do it for all diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: But why can't we do so ?

Comment: Not all matrices are normal.